# Found bags of LEGO bricks at a thrift store. What sets they belong to?

Tags: set-identification

I am wondering if anyone can try and help me identify these bags. I picked them up a thrift store and all my googling has come up empty handed

This is the first bag
[image: Here is the first bag]

Second one
[image: Here is the Second bag]

Third one
[image: Here is the Third bag]

Then there was this small one with no identifications on it
[image: And then there was this small bag with no identifications on it]

And finally these loose pieces
[image: And finally these loose pieces]

Answer (score 2):

Those all look like parts from set [31109 Pirate Ship](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31109-1#T=I) released in 2020 :
[image]

Note this assumes the colors aren't accurately represented in your pictures. Eg. the 10 loose pieces appear to be reddish brown from your picture, but would be medium nougat in the set. Additionally, dark azure parts look like regular blue, yellow like pearl gold, pearl gold like brown, dark bluish gray like black, etc. in your pictures. Ie. all colors appear darker in your pictures than they'd be in real life.